# Geometry question with perpendicular lines and angle bisectors in triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

For any triangle ABC

1) Draw angle bisector of angle BAC. Draw perpendicular bisector of BC. Mark the intersection point as D.

2) Draw altitudes from D to AB and AC. (Extend line as necessary).

Prove BE = CF.

This problem seems to simple but for some reason, I do not have any idea on how to solve this. Can someone give me a hint?

I have made a little bit of progress, noticing that D is always outside the triangle and one of E, F is outside the triangle as well. I am able to prove the first fact (Using some "kinda-coordinate-geometry"). However, I am not sure about the second fact. Will this two help?

Thank you a lot,
Gareth

Edit 1: The kinda-coordinate-geometry is pretty simple. WLOG let AB <= AC.  The intersection of the angle bisector of BAC will split BC into AB: AC ratio (Angle bisector theorem) while the perpendicular bisector splits it to 1: 1. Since AB <= AC, the line intersects "to the left" of the perpendicular bisector. Therefore they intersect below BC. Yes, this is really rigorous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because AD is the angle bisector, the right triangles AED and AFD are congruent, which leads to DE = DF. Also, because the point D is on the perpendicular bisector of the side BC, DB = DC.

As a result, the right triangles BDE and CFD are congruent, which yields BE = CF.

Comment: Orz. Can this also help to prove why one of E, F must be outside the triangle, if true at all? Thank you.

Comment: @Gareth Ma - I think it’s right. But not sure how to prove it.