# Geometry question about angle bisector and perpendicular lines in triangle.

Tags: geometry

This is a follow-up question on [Geometry question with perpendicular lines and angle bisectors in triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490078/geometry-question-with-perpendicular-lines-and-angle-bisectors-in-triangle/3490089?noredirect=1#comment7176792_3490089).

The construction is the same as that question:

For any triangle ABC

1) Draw angle bisector of angle BAC. Draw perpendicular bisector of BC. Mark the intersection point as D.

2) Draw altitudes from D to AB and AC. (Extend line as necessary).

Last time I asked BE = CF and it was solved in that post. However, I am trying to prove another observation I found while messing around in Geogebra:

- One of point E, F is always outside the triangle ABC.
  [image]

I still have no idea on how to prove it. Using my best coordinate geometry I am not able to get much progress, as it is not the best way to deal with distances and angle bisectors, obviously. (lol) Hope I can get some hint.

Thank you,

Gareth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true unless $E$ and $F$ coincide with $B$ and $C$, respectively. But we can call this a degenerate case (it occurs when $AB=AC$). Note that $D$ lies on the circumscribed circle of $\triangle ABC$. This is a well-known fact for your construction. Thus,
$$\angle DBA+\angle DCA=180^{\circ}$$
which means that one of those angles has to be $\geq 90^{\circ}$, say $\angle DCA$. This will force the foot of the perpendicular from $D$ to $AC$ to lie on its extension, i.e., outside the triangle. And it means that the other foot lies internally on the side.

**Update**: Responding to OP's comment, to show that $D$ lies on the circumscribed circle, let the perpendicular bisector meet the circle at point $D_1$. Our aim is to show $D_1\equiv D$. We have $\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}} BD_1=CD_1 \Rightarrow$ arcs $\arc{BD_1}=\arc{CD_1}\Rightarrow \angle CAD_1 =\angle BAD_1$ so $D_1$ is also on the angle bisector, thus $D\equiv D_1$.

Comment: Can you explain further on why D is on the circumcircle?

Comment: @GarethMa Yes, in the meantime you can convince yourself by drawing it on your plot

Comment: @GarethMa see my update

Comment: Thank you for that, it makes sense now.

Comment: @GarethMa I can give you another problem for this construction: If $I$ is the incenter, show that $DB=DC=DI$.

Comment: I really need help with geometry :( Can I have a hint @bjorn93

Comment: @GarethMa It's just angle chasing. Also, remember that $\angle A+\angle BDC=180^{\circ}$, as we showed.

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/mghp3z56 This is my proof.